How do I set a classpath inside the JAR file on Intellij?
I want to set the classpath to be in the JAR file so that the JAR file compiles the entire project directory. Basically my app is supossed to compile .java files and run them so I've decided to have the JAR file cover the entire project director. That way, I can run all the .java files. That's where the issue comes from, I don't know how to do that on Intellij and can't seem to find my problem online.

As shown in the screenshot, I tried making my JAR file by selecting it to be entire category (ou1app is the project directory containing everything) but that doesn't seem to work. If you have any other solution, let me know.
